# How do you prevent sanitization of tags in a Rails helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I'm stuck trying to get this helper to work properly. This is what I have but it assuredly does not work.

```
def registration_link step, step_number
  path = registration_path step
  classes = []
  classes << 'current' if current_step?(step)
  # how do I add the following line to appear before the link ?
  step_icon = "<span class='step_number'>#{step_number}</span>"
  link_to step_icon + t("registration.menu.#{step}"), path, :class => classes.join(' ')
end
```

I am trying to get `step_icon` to appear within the `link_to` and before the word generated by `t("registration.menu.#{step}")`

It seems I can sometimes get in there, but the tags `<>` are sanitized as well..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

link_to can accept a block to link to, normally like so:

```
link_to @account do
  image_tag @account.image.url
end
```

So you could (probably needs refactoring):

```
link_to path, :class => classes.join(' ') do
  "<span class='step_number'>#{step_number}</span>" + t("registration.menu.#{step}")
end
```

to render your strings as html, rather than escaped strings, you add `.html_safe` after.

Alternatively, you could create a tag like so

```
content_tag(:span, step_number, :class=>"step_number")
```

Comment: Content_Tag tothe rescue! Thanks so much Jesse!

Answer (score 1):

Why `classes` are an `Array`?
I would write this that

```
def registration_link step, step_number
  css_class = if current_step?(step) then 'current' else '' end
  link_to registration_path(step), :class => css_class do
    content_tag(:span, step_number, class: 'step_number') + t("registration.menu.#{step}")
  end
end
```